# NHibernate Query to json results are unexpected

Tags: c#, json, nhibernate, queryover

I'm building a webapplication with .Net Core using web api, angular 2 and NHibernate.
I have the following tables in my database:

Todo

```
ID
Name
Priority
```

Priority

```
ID
Name
```

And the following mapping for these tables:

```
[Class(NameType = typeof(Todo), Table = "Todo")]
public class Todo
{
    [ID(-2, Name = "ID")]
    [Generator(-1, Class = "native")]
    public virtual long ID { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]
    public virtual Priority Priority { get; set; }
}

[Class (NameType = typeof(Priority), Table = "Priority")]
public class Priority
{
    [ID(-2, Name = "ID")]
    [Generator(-1, Class = "native")]
    public virtual long ID { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I also have the following DTO that I want to create a list of and send it to the client in json:
For the purpose of this example I have stripped some other properties from it.

```
public class TodoDTO
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Priority Priority { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the query below:

```
var session = SessionFactoryConfigurationBase.GetSessionFactory().GetCurrentSession();

var query = session.QueryOver<Todo>();

TodoDTO todoSummary = null;

query.SelectList(list => list
    .Select(t => t.ID).WithAlias(() => todoSummary.ID)
    .Select(t => t.Name).WithAlias(() => todoSummary.Name)
    .Select(t => t.Priority).WithAlias(() => todoSummary.Priority))
.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<TodoDTO>());
```

the resulting json doesn't show the `ID` and `Name` properties of `Priority` but it shows the following:

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "name":"TEST",
    "priority":
    {
        "__interceptor":
        {
            "persistentClass":"Todo, ApplicationName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "identifier":2,
            "isUninitialized":true,
            "unwrap":false,
            "session":null,
            "entityName": "Priority",
            "isReadOnlySettingAvailable":false
        }
    }
}]
```

Why is it not showing the `ID` and `Name` properties but the class definition instead?
When i create a separate list from the above query I get the result I expected in the fist place but that seems rather cumbersome.

---------------------  EDIT -------------------------

As requested the code that does give me the result i expect:

```
public IList<Todo> GetTodos()
{
        var session = SessionFactoryConfigurationBase.GetSessionFactory().GetCurrentSession();

    var query = session.QueryOver<Todo>()
    .Fetch(t => t.Priority).Eager
    .List<Todo>();

    if(!query.Any())
    {
        return null;
    }

    var result = (
        from t in query
        select new TodoDTO
        {
            ID = t.ID,
            Name = t.Name,
            Priority = t.Priority
        }
    ).ToList();        

    return result;
}
```

The result is return to the client with the following code:

```
public JsonResult GetTodos()
{
    var todos = GetTodos();

    return new JsonResult(todos);
}
```

Comment: Which line is generating the JSON? Can you show us the alternative you wrote that did work?

Comment: I don't think you've 'materialised' your results by using the `List()` method on the resulting `query`.

Comment: @David Osborne: I'm actually quite sure that is the problem but I don't know how to fix that exactly.

Comment: Can you talk us through why you don't want to use the way you already have that works?

Comment: I have been using Linq to SQL for years and with that I can shape my results within the query itself. With QueryOver I need more code to do the same thing it seems. I just want to make sure that I'm doing it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a neater way to accomplish what you want:

```
var todos = 
    session
        .Query<Todo>()
        .Fetch(t => t.Priority)
        .Select(t => 
            new {
               t.ID,
               t.Name,
               Priority = new {
                   t.Priority.Id,
                   t.Prioriry.Name}
            })
        .ToList();

return new JsonResult(todos);
```

I've omitted the DTO to demonstrate that it's not strictly necessary. However, the `Select()` call could be changed to create a new DTO instead.

> I just want to make sure that I'm doing it right.

When it comes to `QueryOver()` and `Query()`, there is no 'right way'. I find `Query()` is often more readable and neater but sometimes lacks the control I might need. I generally start with `Query()` and 'escalate' to `QueryOver()` if I get stuck or I am not happy the SQL `Query()` is generating.

Answer (score 1):

```
query.SelectList(list => list
    .Select(t => t.ID).WithAlias(() => todoSummary.ID)
    .Select(t => t.Name).WithAlias(() => todoSummary.Name)
    .Select(t => t.Priority).WithAlias(() => todoSummary.Priority))
.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<TodoDTO>());
```

The likely cause of your issue is that you aren't assigning the result of this line of code to a variable.

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "name":"TEST",
    "priority":
    {
        "__interceptor":
        {
            "persistentClass":"Todo, ApplicationName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "identifier":2,
            "isUninitialized":true,
            "unwrap":false,
            "session":null,
            "entityName": "Priority",
            "isReadOnlySettingAvailable":false
        }
    }
}]
```

**The above JSON that you are receiving is likely because you are converting the `query` variable to JSON rather than the result of the `SelectList` call.**

Comment: Ok, I can understand that but how can I do this properly then?

Comment: According the following article it's not possible to populate entities to a property: http://www.andrewwhitaker.com/blog/2014/06/19/queryover-series-part-4-transforming/

Comment: "You cannot populate full entities (e.g., .Select(() => productReview.Product).WithAlias(() => result.Product))" In the paragraph before the last one of the AliasToBean section

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155082/discussion-between-bunnynut-and-mjwills).